# How can I satisfy "#if canImport" in Swift macro unit tests?

Tags: swift, swift5.9

I'm trying out the macro support in Swift 5.9. I created a new macro package using:

```
swift package init --type macro
```

And in the example, unit tests come with:

```
    func testMacro() throws {
        #if canImport(SelfNamedMacros)
        assertMacroExpansion(
            """
            #stringify(a + b)
            """,
            expandedSource: """
            (a + b, "a + b")
            """,
            macros: testMacros
        )
        #else
        throw XCTSkip("macros are only supported when running tests for the host platform")
        #endif
    }
```

But I can't see actually how to make `#if canImport(SelfNamedMacros)` true and run the example test (my new macro package, i.e., the package directory, was named "SelfNamed").
That is, when I run the test, it always uses the `XCTSkip` path.

---

When I select:

[image]

I get the issue I had. I.e., "canImport" is false.

When I select:

[image]
The tests run as expected.

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: I open the package in Xcode (`open Package.swift` at the command line), then go into the test and run by tapping on the triangle beside the test in the Xcode UI. Curiously though I can't now repro this problem on a different mac OS system (`13.6 (22G120)`) and running Xcode `Version 15.0 (15A240d)`. It runs the test successfully finding that `canImport(SelfNamedMacros)` is true.  I was getting this issue on another system (latest MacOS, Sonoma, 14.1, Xcode 15.1 beta 2). Downloading the Xcode 15.1 beta 2 now on current mac system to try for a repro.

Comment: OK-- I get a repro by selecting as a platform, an ios simulator. Selecting "My Mac" allows the tests to run. So, "host platform" means the Mac OS system I'm assuming. I'll put screen grabs in an answer to this question.